# How to dynamically set permissions for ALL channels discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

So I was making a mute command, and I couldn't find a way to set permissions for every single channel and exclude changing permissions for private channels.

So for example, setting channel permissions is as follows:

```js
message.channel.updateOverwrite(role1, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false,
      SPEAK: false,
      ADD_REACTIONS: false,
      READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
});
message.channel.updateOverwrite(role2, {
     SEND_MESSAGES: null,
     SPEAK: null,
     ADD_REACTIONS: null,
})
```

This only sets the permissions for the channel in which the command was executed, I would like to know if there is a way to set permissions for every single channel in the server (except private channels ← if this isn't possible then ignore it), and I know you could set permissions for every single channel using channel IDs but that would be limited to 1 discord server and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all channels in the server and mute them using something like this

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => { //Get each channel
    if (channel.type === "text") { //Check if it's a text channel
        try {
            channel.updateOverwrite(role1, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                SPEAK: false,
                ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
            });

            channel.updateOverwrite(role2, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: null,
                SPEAK: null,
                ADD_REACTIONS: null,
            });
        } catch (error) { //Run this if there was an error setting the permissions
            //Error handling code here
        };
    };
});
```

All this code is doing is getting a list of every channel in the server, ignoring the voice channels, and setting the permissions. If your bot doesn't have permission to edit the channel, the `catch` block is executed. You can simply have it `return`, send an error message, whatever you want.